# How to add a prefix (1) to byte?

Tags: c#

How to add a prefix (1) to byte?

Example:

`byte1 = 36`

...how to get:

`byte2 = 136`

Comment: `byte1 += 10;` would do it.

Comment: What output is expected if `byte1` is 0? 4? 40? 41?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range of `byte` is from 0 to 255 ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types)). You need to consider overflow after prefixing 1.

```
byte b = 36;
var s = $"1{b}"; // Prefix 1
if (byte.TryParse(s, out var result))
{
    // Handle result
}
else
{
    // Handle overflow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `byte.TryParse`, you could do it magnitudes more efficiently (with no *allocations*) using an `if`, or a [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) with just a handful of CPU instructions

if you are assured that your byte will never exceed the value of 100

```
byte byte1 = 36;
    
byte1 += (byte)(byte1 < 10 ? 10 : 100);
```

<sub>***Note** : Just be wary of overflow*</sub>

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sn7onz)

---

Or use [`checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) to verify the sanity of what you are doing

> The checked keyword is used to explicitly enable overflow checking for
> integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions.

```
checked { byte1 += (byte)(value < 10 ? 10 : value < 100  ? 100 : 1000); }
```

Or just throw

```
byte1 += (byte)(value < 10 ? 10 : value < 100  ? 100 : throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong, you have done");
```

Or you can make your own *extension*. Also since this can be trivially *inlined* you could mark it with `AggressiveInlining` to save a call to the stack

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static byte Prefix1(this byte value)
{
    checked { return value += (byte)(value < 10 ? 10 : value < 100  ? 100 : 1000); }
}
    
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public static byte Prefix2(this byte value)
    => (byte)(value < 10 ? value + 10 : value < 100  ? value + 100 : throw new InvalidOperationException("Wrong, you have done"));
```

Usage

```
var result = byte1.AddPrefix1();
var result2 = byte1.AddPrefix2();
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YPRdnf)